# OkHttp error: stream was reset: INTERNAL_ERROR

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, okhttp

I'm using Retrofit to fetch data from a Covid 19 statistics API. Fetching data for every country works except the US. When I fetch Covid 19 cases in the US, it throws the exception below. I've tried increasing the timeout for the httpClient to 2 minutes but it doesn't work.

```kotlin
2020-09-27 17:14:07.463 31948-31948/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.covid19moniterapp, PID: 31948
    okhttp3.internal.http2.StreamResetException: stream was reset: INTERNAL_ERROR
        at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Stream$FramingSource.read(Http2Stream.java:420)
        at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Codec$StreamFinishingSource.read(Http2Codec.java:205)
        at okio.RealBufferedSource.read(RealBufferedSource.java:51)
        at okio.RealBufferedSource.exhausted(RealBufferedSource.java:61)
        at okio.InflaterSource.refill(InflaterSource.java:102)
        at okio.InflaterSource.read(InflaterSource.java:62)
        at okio.GzipSource.read(GzipSource.java:80)
        at okio.RealBufferedSource.read(RealBufferedSource.java:51)
        at okio.ForwardingSource.read(ForwardingSource.java:35)
        at retrofit2.OkHttpCall$ExceptionCatchingResponseBody$1.read(OkHttpCall.java:288)
        at okio.RealBufferedSource.request(RealBufferedSource.java:72)
```

[Link to the json I'm trying to load](https://api.covid19api.com/dayone/country/us)

This happens when I do the following call in my code:

```kotlin
    // Code in the viewModel 
    val currentCountry = CurrentCountryObject.currentRetrofitService.getCurrentWeatherAsync("us").await()

    // Actual code that contains GET request
    interface CurrentCountryApiService {
        @GET("dayone/country/{countryName}")
        fun getCurrentWeatherAsync(
            @Path("countryName") countryName: String
        ): Deferred<List<CurrentCountryItem>>
    }
```

I've tried searching for explanations but I can't get any. Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you solved this problem?

Comment: The problem was that I was trying to load a really large JSON file. I tested on Chrome and it brought the same error so I changed my API endpoint to one with less JSON.

Comment: I solved this problem with the same reason, and I changed some setting in Nginx like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65137191/okhttp-keeps-getting-streamresetexception-stream-was-reset-internal-error-when