# OkHttp keeps getting StreamResetException: stream was reset: INTERNAL_ERROR when it's 200

Tags: android, django, okhttp, http2

I got `StreamResetException: stream was reset: INTERNAL_ERROR` from OkHttp. What's the problem?

Here's the logs.

```
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: <-- 200 https://www.example.com/user/list (396ms)
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: date: Fri, 04 Dec 2020 02:21:35 GMT
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: content-type: application/json
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: content-length: 99730
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: server: nginx/1.18.0
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: allow: GET, HEAD, OPTIONS
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: x-frame-options: DENY
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: x-content-type-options: nosniff
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: referrer-policy: same-origin
D/okhttp.Http2: << 0x00000003  5792 DATA          
D/okhttp.Http2: << 0x00000003     4 RST_STREAM    
D/okhttp.TaskRunner: Q10092 canceled              : OkHttp ConnectionPool
D/force: okhttp3.internal.http2.StreamResetException: stream was reset: INTERNAL_ERROR
D/okhttp.Http2: >> 0x00000000     8 GOAWAY     
D/okhttp.TaskRunner: Q10096 finished run in 216 ms: OkHttp www.example.com
```

This is issued in Okhttp Gihub Repository. But any issues haven't solved yet.

I called the API like this

```
    @Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
    @GET("/user/list")
    fun getUserList(@Header("Authorization") jwt: String): Call<ArrayList<UserData>>
```

It's 200 but I get nothing. It's very weird behaviour..

Is it a server problem or my problem? (The server is Django).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

it was Nginx buffer size problem.

If you are using AWS EC2,

Go to `/etc/nginx/default.d/server.conf`

And set,

```
proxy_redirect off;
proxy_buffering off;
```

Answer (score 3):

As suggested in OkHttp issue tracker, mostly likely this is a server error after the headers are sent.

https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/3936

> Typically error code is sent by a server to indicate a problem server-side. It could also happen if OkHttp’s stream reader crashes with an unexpected exception.

I'd suggest checking for server errors if you can, but you can see the Http2 frame from the server here

```
D/okhttp.Http2: << 0x00000003     4 RST_STREAM
```

Answer (score 3):

StreamResetException: Error code is sent by a server to indicate a problem server-side. It can be due to Nginx buffer size issue can also happen if overload a single server with multiple requests

Answer (score 1):

The same error was shown while reading images from a remote server by coil library (that deep inside called OkHttp).

Header
*accept-encoding: identity*
made things work. Maybe OkHttp cannot correctly parse gzip encoding returned by nginx.